# Use tc qdisc netem to emulate delay, but ssh gets slow down

Tags: networking, tc

I have 3 VMs, A, B, and C. These VMs are all under the same network.

On VM A, I use the following commands to introduce a delay to VM B.

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: prio
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip dst VM_B_IP flowid 2:1
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1 handle 2: netem delay 1000ms
```

Now, inside VM A I ping VM B and get 1000ms latency. If I ping VM C, I get <1ms latency.

The weird thing is, my ssh connection to VM A also has a 1000ms delay now, no matter where I ssh it from. But if I ping VM A, I still get normal <1ms latency.

It seems that netem delay works only on the specified IP, but somehow the ssh connection is also affected. What could cause this?